# `import matplotlib.pyplot` or `import pylab`?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Excuse the blunt question, but what's the difference between `import pylab` and `import matplotlib.pyplot`? I realized my coworker and I have been using different imports and, to the best of our knowledge, there is no difference between the two imports.

Does anyone choose one over the other for a specific reason? What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_pylab_module.htm):

> PyLab is a convenience module that bulk imports matplotlib.pyplot (for plotting) and NumPy (for Mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space.

So `pylab` imports more things than the latter. As long as you only use `matplotlib.pyplot` functions they should be equivalent.

That being said, the docs also mention that it's deprecated:

> Although many examples use PyLab, it is no longer recommended

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pylab, it just imports a bunch of junk into the namespace. It was originally intended to provide an environment familiar to people coming from MATLAB.

Instead, use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Note that pylab's doc itself recommends not to use it:

```
>>> print(pylab.__doc__)

.. warning::
   Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected
   behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use `matplotlib.pyplot`
   instead.

`pylab` is a module that includes `matplotlib.pyplot`, `numpy`, `numpy.fft`,
`numpy.linalg`, `numpy.random`, and some additional functions, all within
a single namespace. Its original purpose was to mimic a MATLAB-like way
of working by importing all functions into the global namespace. This is
considered bad style nowadays.
```